# Setting dfs.blocksize to 100Kb in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, properties, hdfs

I try to set the `dfs.blocksize` in Hadoop to 100Kb which is less than the default `dfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size`, which is 1MB.

When I copy the file like

```
hdfs dfs -Ddfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size=0 -Ddfs.blocksize=102400 inp.txt /input/inp.txt
```

I still get,

```
copyFromLocal: Specified block size is less than configured minimum value (dfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size): 102400 < 1048576
```

I tried to add this property in `hdfs-site.xml` as well. But `dfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size` does not seem to change.

How else would I change this property?

Comment: Why are you changing the default block size to over 1000 times smaller than the default?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the value of the dfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size property in the /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml file and restarting the NameNode, as this may be a final property which cannot be overridden by a command line setting.